# Highchart Map Horizontal Legend Witdh

Tags: highcharts, legend

Is it possible to change size of legend when layout is horizontal? I have code

```
"legend":{
  "layout":"horizontal",
  "align":"center",
  "verticalAlign":"bottom",
  "width":300,
  "itemWidth":100,
  "floating":{
     "enabled":true
  }
```

Whatever i change legend with add width, itemWidth, or enable floating, this is useless

Comment: I am not sure what do you have in mind, changing the width works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2639fsz/ Could you reproduce your attempts?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Can u use it on highchart map?

Comment: yeah sure, there is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5wk4jehy/